# Calculate lessthan value using NSExpression?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, operators, nsexpression

For the following block of code:

```
NSString *formul=@"5 < 9";

NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:formul];

int result = [[e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil] intValue];

NSLog(@"formule:%d", result);
```

I got error:

> due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "5 < 9 == 1"'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSPredicate` instead:

```
NSString *formul = @"15 < 9";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:formul];
BOOL b = [predicate evaluateWithObject:nil];
```

In **Swift:**

```
let formula = "15 < 9"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: formula)
let b = predicate.evaluate(with: nil)
print(b) // false
```

Comment: It works fine...Using NSExpression that @"5 < 9" not possible?

Comment: @prabu: Probably not, at least I don't know a solution.